Alternatives for SetInterval in the Lightning web components
I am using the SetInterval for a functionality in the LWC Javascript. I see that the setInterval is not working exactly after every specified time interval/time duration. The time interval that I have is 60000ms. From my side, I have tried using web workers but I get this error:

I understand that the web workers cannot be used as the lighting locker services prevent them from using. What are the other good alternatives that I have that I can use in place of the setInterval function in the JS?

Can you post your code and elaborate on how setInterval() is "not working exactly after every specified time interval/time duration".
